# How can I store Geojson response into Postgres Database using node-express?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgis, geojson

**NOTE:** Geojson response contains coordinates datatype, which needs to be stored in Postgres as geometry datatype.

I don't want to use any 3rd party software like Qgis or ArcGIS, or command line tool such as geojson2psql in Postgis.

Comment: What's your table look like? Do you have a `geom` column? Do you have PostGIS installed? Do you know about the PostGIS method `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`? This is actually a better question to ask on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use a [jsonb](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/) column.

It's simple to query a jsonb column for specific attributes, using the `->` operator. For example, assuming a column name of "geodata", this query:

```
SELECT geodata->'geometry'->'coordinates' AS coords FROM geo_example;
```

...would return **[-104.99404, 39.75621]** from this GeoJSON example I grabbed from [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/):

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87157/4) showing a couple examples.

Comment: Thank you. This may work.
But I need to store data in Postgres DB only of type geometry, instead of jsonb. I cannot alter my table now.
Need node implementation if possible.

Comment: Can you update your question and include your table's definition? At least the column you're looking to insert into.

Comment: is there any documentation, example anything for inserting data in to a Point type column in postgress with a rest API. I mean something I could test with postman ??